# how can i write rule with hibernate validator : field1 not null or field2 not null

Tags: bean-validation

```
public class User {
    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    @???
    private String email;
    @???
    private String mobile;
}
```

how can i write rule with hibernate validator(@???), like this code:

StringUtils.hasText(email)  || StringUtils.hasText(mobile)

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at how to implement [class level constraints](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-usingvalidator-classlevel). This feature is described in the Bean Validation specification as well as the Hibernate Validator online docs.